# Hadoop/Hive - Split a single row into multiple rows

Tags: hadoop, split, hive

I'm trying to find a way to split a row in Hive into multiple rows based on a delimited column.  For instance taking a result set:

```
ID1  Subs
1     1, 2
2     2, 3
```

And returning:

```
ID1  Subs
1     1
1     2
2     2
2     3
```

I've found some road signs at http://osdir.com/ml/hive-user-hadoop-apache/2009-09/msg00092.html, however I wasn't able enough detail to point me in the direction of a solution, and I don't know how I would set up the transform function to return an object that would split the rows.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this wording

```
SELECT ID1, Sub
FROM tableName lateral view explode(split(Subs,',')) Subs AS Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID1, new_Subs_clmn
FROM tableName lateral view explode(split(Subs,',')) Subs AS new_Sub_clmn;
```

I was initially confused with the names used, sharing the above query thinking it would be of help.