# Hive - Hashtag Counting

Tags: hadoop, count, hive, hiveql

I get stuck by counting hashtags with HiveQL.
My problem:
I have these format of the hashtags in one row:

---

> jurassicworld;movie;night;dino
>
> jurassicWorld;book;yourtickets;movie
>
> jurassicWorld;movie

---

I looked at the https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF from Hive, but there is no function, which i can choose a delimiter (;) to seperat these hashtags and count them.

my result should be look like this:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Hashtag       | Count     |
+---------------+-----------+
| jurassicworld | 300       |
| movie         | 200       |
| night         | 100       |
| dino          | 250       | 
| book          | 50        |  
| etc...        | 100       |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hive: converting a comma separated string to array for table generating function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754648/hive-converting-a-comma-separated-string-to-array-for-table-generating-function) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160304/hadoop-hive-split-a-single-row-into-multiple-rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160304/hadoop-hive-split-a-single-row-into-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created following dummy table deli -

```
hive> describe deli;
OK
row1                    string                  None
```

I used following query -

```
select hashTag, count(*) as data from deli LATERAL VIEW explode(split(row1,'\\;')) t1 AS hashTag group by hashTag;
```

And, its giving me following result for your data-

```
book    1
dino    1
jurassicWorld   2
jurassicworld   1
movie   3
night   1
yourtickets     1
```