# Hive - Use lateral view explode(split()) on join table

Tags: sql, hive, split

I want to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786898/11561121) simple topic on a more complicated example. This is my try:

```
SELECT maxxx.COD_ENTREP as ID_ENTITE,
    maxxx.COD_ENTREP_ASSU as ID_ENTITE_GARANTE,
    maxxx.ID_NOTIFICATION as ID_NOTIFICATION,
    maxxx.OBJET_METIER as OBJET_METIER,
    REF_EXT_OBJET_METIER,
    case when maxxx.typ_mvt="S" then 1 else 0 end AS TOP_SUPP,
    case when maxxx.typ_mvt = "S" then to_date(substr(maxxx.dt_capt, 1, 11)) else null end AS DT_SUPP,
    minnn.typ_mvt as MIN_MVT,
    maxxx.typ_mvt as MAX_MVT,
    case when minnn.typ_mvt = 'C' then 'C' else 'M' end as TYP_MVT

FROM 

(select s.id_notification, s.dt_capt, s.typ_mvt from ${use_database}.pz_send_notification as s
join
(select id_notification, min(dt_capt) as dtmin from ${use_database}.pz_send_notification group by id_notification) as minn
on s.id_notification=minn.id_notification and s.dt_capt=minn.dtmin) as minnn

join

(select s.id_notification, s.dt_capt, s.typ_mvt, s.cod_entrep, s.cod_entrep_assu, s.objet_metier from ${use_database}.pz_send_notification as s
join
(select id_notification, max(dt_capt) as dtmax from ${use_database}.pz_send_notification group by id_notification) as maxx
on s.id_notification=maxx.id_notification and s.dt_capt=maxx.dtmax) as maxxx

on minnn.id_notification=maxxx.id_notification 

lateral view explode(split(maxxx.OBJET_METIER, ";")) maxxx.OBJET_METIER as ee;
```

I want to apply the split function on a table that was created using multiple joins.

But I keep on having this error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 28:0 missing EOF at 'lateral' near 'id_notification'
```

**EDIT**

This is the result of the query **without the final line (lateral view explode)**:

[image]

What I want to have is a table with 4 lines. The three first are the result of the duplication of the ref_ext_objet_metier_column using split on ";".

Comment: would you be able to show us the table data and expected results?

Comment: I just edited my questio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolon has special meaning in Hive and should be shielded. Use double-slash in Hive:

```
split(maxxx.OBJET_METIER, '\\;')
```

Also the alias is wrong. Give correct alias to the lateral view, like this:

```
lateral view explode(split(maxxx.OBJET_METIER, '\\;')) om as splitted_col
```

And address it in the query as `om.splitted_col` for example.

If you are using beeline and `'\\;'` does not work, try `'\073'`:

```
lateral view explode(split(maxxx.OBJET_METIER, '\073')) om as splitted_col
```